# Access Microphone / Camera in background in Android 11

Tags: android, android-11

Access to the `Microphone` in the background is stopped in `Android 11`. There are only 3 options, Allow when in-use, Allow once, and Deny.

How to make the app get access to the microphone in the background all the time in `Android 11`? Is there any workaround?

Comment: No, its for security reason they got this after long time on Android. But more possibly you can use foreground service again with some trade-off. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/foreground-services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new Android Developer Policy restricts access to Microphone and Camera in the background.

Using `Accessibility Service` one can still use the feature in the background. However, the notification will always be on.

Comment: Do you have a documentation reference for this, where I can find out more details?

Answer (score 5):

Now we have to specify a type for our foreground service (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#types):

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <service ...
        android:foregroundServiceType="camera|microphone" />
</manifest>
```

But in some cases our foreground service can't still access camera or microphone even if we specified `android:foregroundServiceType`:

If a foreground service was started while app was in background (wasn't visible to a user - no visible activities), for example on device boot (`BOOT_COMPLETED`) broadcast, then such service can't start using camera, microphone

If a foreground service was started while app was in foreground (was visible to a user - some visible activity) then such service can start using camera, microphone

Info from: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#bg-access-restrictions

My issue [Camera2 cameraManager.openCamera exception from time to time on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67284842/camera2-cameramanager-opencamera-exception-from-time-to-time-on-some-devices)

Comment: This seems to be no longer true: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#bg-access-restrictions Even if the app starts the service while in foreground "the service can access the microphone only while the app is running in the foreground"

Comment: @Eric well my question already explains it and has that link...

Comment: You wrote "then such service can start using camera, microphone", but as I understand the android documentation I linked, it should be "then such service can start using camera, microphone only while your app is foreground". In the documentation it explicitly reads that "If the user has granted the RECORD_AUDIO permission to your app, the service can access the microphone only while the app is running in the foreground."

Comment: Thanks man @user924, saved a lot of time.

Comment: @Eric foreground service

Answer (score 1):

To access background mic / camera / location in Android 11 there are some exemptions given by Android , you need to qualify one of these conditions:

Refer: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#restrictions-exemptions

> Exemptions to while-in-use restrictions:
>
> - When a foreground service starts in one of the following situations, the service is exempt from the restrictions on while-in-use access to location, camera, and microphone:
> - The service is started by a system component.
> - The service is started by interacting with app widgets.
> - The service is started by interacting with a notification.
> - The service is started as a `PendingIntent` that is sent from a different, visible app.
> - The service is started by an app that is a device policy controller that is running in device owner mode.
> - The service is started by an app which provides the `VoiceInteractionService`.
> - The service is started by an app that has the `START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND` privileged permission.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67284842/camera2-cameramanager-opencamera-exception-from-time-to-time-on-some-devices - here I described in such case camera can't be accessed in a foreground service