# Camera2 cameraManager.openCamera exception from time to time on some devices

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I have an app which records videos, it has about 80K current installations (more than 100K downloads), Crashlytics statistics seems to be good - Crash-free users 99.66% and rating on Google Play is also OK - 4.5

But still for some of my users can happen the next errors (it may happened for such user once or a couple of times by now, so not often, but still happens from time to time):

- `android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISABLED (1): connectHelper:1578: Camera "0" disabled by policy`
- `android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISCONNECTED (2): Camera service is currently unavailable`
- `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: supportsCameraApi:2096: Unknown camera ID 0`
- `android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISABLED (1): validateClientPermissionsLocked:1066: Caller "com.MY_APP_PACKAGE" (PID 10237, UID 21433) cannot open camera "1" when sensor privacy is enabled`

on opening camera using `camera2` API:

```
...
    cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, mainHandler)`
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    openReportErrorDialog(e) // so a user could report this issue
...
```

Reported devices:

- Vivo 1906
- Wheatek BV5500Plus
- Samsung SM-N975F
- Samsung SM-G988W
- Samsung SM-A520F
- Motorola REVVLRY
- HUAWEI VOG-L09
- HUAWEI STK-LX1
- HUAWEI MRD-LX1
- HUAWEI FIG-LX1
- Coolpad CP3669AS
- Infinix X655C

Android versions: from 8 to 11 (app min SDK is 6)

So basically it can work fine for a specific user for some time, no issues when opening camera, but from time to time this exception can occur for such user

I don't have any idea why it happens. I can't reproduce this issue on my own devices (two Samsung, one Lenovo, one Huawei and one Xiaomi devices), only users can report such issue from time to time...

The most nonsense exception here is `Unknown camera ID 0`, because before opening camera I get list of available cameras, so it's not hardcoded, it's not possible that such camera id doesn't exist, and a user said that before this error that camera was working ok

**UPDATE**

Found this

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#bg-access-restrictions

So it seems if a foreground service was started by system (on `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast, declared in manifest) and not by app (if a user launch app) then it can't access camera and microphone.

So basically after rebooting a device we can't automatically start camera anymore without user interaction.

Really bad for dashboard camera applications for car drivers...

They added `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`, but there is no `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_CAMERA` and `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_RECORD_AUDIO`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISABLED (1): connectHelper:1578: Camera "0" disabled by policy
```

That either means the device has an enterprise policy installed that disables cameras for example (employers that don't want employees photographing stuff at work), or your app is trying to open the camera in the background, on more recent Android releases.

If it's the policy, there's nothing you can do besides to tell the user that there's a policy in place and to complain to their admins.

```
android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISCONNECTED (2): Camera service is currently unavailable

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: supportsCameraApi:2096: Unknown camera ID 0
```

These usually mean something has crashed in the camera stack - until things restart (takes a few seconds usually), all cameras will be reported as unknown.
Ideally that'll never happen, but bugs unfortunately exist even on the best devices. A retry a few seconds later will probably work, unless the camera hardware on the phone is failing in some way that leads to a persistent crash.

```
android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISABLED (1): validateClientPermissionsLocked:1066: Caller "com.MY_APP_PACKAGE" (PID 10237, UID 21433) cannot open camera "1" when sensor privacy is enabled
```

This means the OEM has some kind of 'shut off all cameras' feature like airplane mode is for radios.  Like the enterprise policy above, this is something out of your control - the user needs to re-enable camera access, so all you can do is put up a dialog saying "cameras are disabled, sorry".

Comment: __or your app is trying to open the camera in the background, on more recent Android releases.___ yes, my app (dashcam) can continue or start recording in background (sticky foreground service) but this usually works for most devices even on the latest versions. So some devices can prevent from using camera in background?

Comment: So on some errors I can try to reopen the camera. But which method is better: 1) try `cameraManager.openCamera()` again after a couple of seconds or 2) `cameraManager.registerAvailabilityCallback()`? or the last one usually triggers only when some other app releases a specific camera (stops using it) and for mentioned errors would not be useful?

Comment: "Background" on Android means either a background service, or an app that's no longer visible.  A foreground service with a notification is still allowed to use the camera just fine.

For the case of an "unknown camera ID", waiting for an availability callback should work fine.  But may be simpler to just retry a few times, 500 ms apart or similar.

Comment: Weird. I always start foreground service with notification, for example for auto starting video recording on usb charging start but still such errors like `CAMERA_DISABLED ... cannot open camera "0" from background` on a few devices

Comment: If you can create a sample app that can reproduce the problem, you could file a bug with Android about this; that should reliably work: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192705&template=845803

Comment: I have an option to start camera and recording on boot and it happens in `onStartCommand` of my boot service (it starts from boot completed receiver), I call `startForeground()` in `onCreate` of boot service, so I guess the issue here that at `onStartCommand` service is usual service (not foreground yet), I guess it becomes foreground only after n milliseconds/seconds after `startForeground()` was called, not right away, some delay

Comment: Found this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#bg-access-restrictions - Does it mean that after a device rebooting if my video recording service was started by the system (on `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast, declared in manifest) then it can't access camera? And the only way is when a user has to launch app from launcher icon, then app starts its foreground service, and camera can be accessed by this service? If yes, its really bad for dashcam apps, cause it seems without user interaction service can't start using camera automatically if service was started by system

Comment: Check that officially we can't open camera in background without user interaction on Android 11 after device boot and user didn't open app yet, can do it on Android <= 10 on Samsung, Pixel and some other devices. But bad thing here that some devices like Sony and some others blocks it even on Android 9, 10 (mb 8), they made their own rules. I only found such rules for Android 11 (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#bg-access-restrictions), there is nothing for <= 10. If there was a method to find out if I can open camera in background without actually opening it

Comment: any solution till yet for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

If your app targets Android 10 (API level 29) or higher and accesses location information in a foreground service, declare the location foreground service type as an attribute of your  component.

```
<manifest>
...
<service ... android:foregroundServiceType="location|camera" />
```

At runtime, if the foreground service only needs access to a subset of the types declared in the manifest, you can limit the service's access using the logic in the following code snippet:

```
Notification notification = ...;
Service.startForeground(notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION| FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_CAMERA);
```

This is how you will be able to use camera in the background.